# Multiplying integer by float results in NaN in logcat

Tags: android, floating-point, logcat

So I`m creating a game for Android and I have a variable named screenHeight which is equal to 1080. The following piece of code results in an NaN when I try to output it to logcat:

```
screenHeight * 0.08f;
```

However, when I have this it works perfectly fine:

```
screenHeight * 0.10f;
```

What`s even more strange is that a couple of months ago the first line of code worked perfectly fine. With no changes to the code, the same piece of code stopped working. I am working in Android Studio so maybe the compilation is wrong (bug in Android Studio?) or something in my phone is wrong as I am using USB debugging. I would really appreciate some help thank you!

EDIT:

Now even the second line of code results in NaN.... How is the same piece of code acting differently different times when I am changing nothing else?

Comment: I think they made some changes to logcat in the new update of Android SDK, because I was having some problems that actually got fixed with the new update. 1) What method are you using for debugging (Log.d or some other method?) 2) Does it work if instead of printing the float you print a string like `"" + screenHeight * 0.08f;`?

Comment: It's not just the logcat I am using the calculation in my actual game graphics and my graphics are not being placed properly. I am using Log.d and I have always printed the string way, like "" + screenHeight + 0.08f;

Comment: How are you getting the screenHeight variable?

Comment: Did you have a look at my edit? I think this is not a problem with my code but rather hardware or android studio...

Comment: Maybe, but maybe it could be a problem with how you get screen height, because some methods are not recommended anymore.

Comment: I get it using getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels. But I have another variable named screenWidth that I also get in this way and that variable has no problems even when I multiply it by floating points. It's only the screenHeight one.

Comment: What if you use this method? `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`

Comment: Ok I just emulated the device that I physically have (Samsung s4) and it works fine on the emulator (Even though its the same device). Do you think theres a problem with my phone?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try the method I suggested above?

Comment: I cant because where I am using the displayMetrics is not in a subclass of Activity. But if it was a problem with my way of doing it then how come screenWidth has no problems?

Comment: Do you have any surrounding Activity you can use? You can also use `(WindowManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);` if you have a Context.

Comment: The Android log functions just send a string of text to a log buffer, which logcat prints. No formatting of numbers is involved at that level, so any issue is happening in your Java code. When in doubt, assign values to variables and examine them with a debugger.

Comment: Since you can do `getResources()` it means you have a Context, so you can  use `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` to acquire your DisplayMetrics variable.

Comment: But what I don't understand is how come the exact same piece of code works fine on other devices and emulators but when it comes to my specific device it messes up. Also, sometimes it actually does work fine on my own device. It's unpredictable. Which is why I think there's a problem with my phone. The same piece of code with absolutely no changes should not give completely different results just because it's run at different times of the day...

Comment: Just tell me if the above method works first.

Comment: The way I was doing it started to work again so I can`t tell you if your method made a difference. Like I said, the results keep changing there is no consistency so I can`t tell you which method is working and which isn`t....

Comment: Well, try my method and see if it works 100% of the time that way.